# Adding onclick into the field that's created by adding can_delete to formset

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I add ***onclick="functionName()"*** to the field that is created by using can_delete=True in formset?
<input type="checkbox" name="form-0-DELETE" id="id_form-0-DELETE" ***onclick="functionName()"***>

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in many ways:

## override attribute formset.deletion_widget

```
class MyFormSet(django.forms.Formset):
    deletion_widget = CheckboxInput(attrs={'onclick':"functionName()})
    ...
```

## override class method formset.def get_deletion_widget

```
class MyFormSet(django.forms.Formset):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def get_deletion_widget(cls):
        response = super().get_deletion_widget()
        response.attrs = getattr(response, 'attrs', {}) | {'onclick':"functionName()}
        return response
```

## override instance method add_fields

```
class MyFormSet(django.forms.Formset):
    ...
    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super().add_fields(form, index)
        if DELETION_FIELD_NAME in form.fields:
            widget = form.fields[DELETION_FIELD_NAME].widget
            widget.attrs = getattr(widget, 'attrs', {}) | {'onclick':"functionName()}
```

you can override form.fields on form.**init**, form.fields on render, template with form on render. Many ways to do it.